# How to skip initializing a Git Repository during creation of angular 6 project

Tags: angular

Is there any command to `skip initializing a Git Repository` during angular 6 project creation

I am using `ng new [name]` command to create angular 6 project. by default it is adding git repository.

ng new [name]

Comment: I believe you can with `--skip-git` arg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Updated answer**:
Use `--skip-git` argument instead of deprecated `--skipGit`.

<del>Old answer: You can use `--skipGit` argument.</del>

From docs:

> --skipGit=true|false
>
> When true, does not initialize a git repository.
>
> Default: false
>
> Aliases: -g

[Official docs - See Arguments section](https://angular.io/cli/new).

Answer (score 6):

### To list the available options

```
ng new  --help
```

### To skip Git. This is the command

```
ng new my-app --skip-git
```